# Using JSONPath to get only top level children

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have a JSON array that contains 4 objects each with an `id` field.  The fourth object contains two children that each also have an `id` field.  I want to only get the ids of the 4 top level children; I don't want the ids of the children of the 4th element.

This is a simplified version of the JSON string:

```
[
  {
    "id": 709709537
  },
  {
    "id": 1104067257
  },
  {
    "id": 2961327618
  },
  {
    "id": 9066007668,
    "photo": {
      "id": 461295287,
      "thumbnails": [
        {
          "id": 461295307
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Using JSONPath, `$..id` will get me all 6 id elements, with no way to determine which level they come from, e.g.

```
[  
   709709537,
   1104067257,
   2961327618,
   9066007668,
   461295287,
   461295307
]
```

I expected `$.id` to give me the 4 top level `id` children, but this gets me nothing.

I've researched many pages and tried several experiments using JSON testers (e.g. https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/) and cannot find a JSONPath expression to get just the top 4 children id elements.

Is there a JSONPath expression that will get me just the top level children ids?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it should be

```
$[*].id
```

Remember that you have these in an array, and you want each element in the array.  Then you want their .id afterwards.

Comment: No problem.

Remember to mark accepted answers!  This way other people with a similar problem will see yours was actually solved and had useful information.